# wrapping different datatype into a generic, in scala

Tags: scala, dictionary

I expect to return a map containing value of different datatypes such as
(key -> String) and (key -> Int), but i can have Map either of
Map[String,String] or Map[String,Int].
I can't use class because number and order of keys are not fixed.
Is there any way to wrap String and Int to a generic class so that i can return map as Map[String,Any]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `HMap` as @Harnish suggested, but there is an alternative in the scala library: `Map[String, Either[Int, String]]`. It applies only if you know that the types either one or another and nothing more.

The type `Either[Int, String]` can be created either by `Left(5)` or `Right("Hello")`. Then you can use match to test the value:

```
x match {
  case Left(n) => println(s"$n is a number")
  case Right(s) => println(s"$s is a string")
}
```

**Updated**
Example:

```
val dict = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, Either[String, Int]]()
dict += ("a" -> Right(5))
dict += ("b" -> Left("Hello"))

dict map {
  case (key, Right(n)) => println(s"For $key: $n is integer")
  case (key, Left(s)) => println(s"For $key: $s is string")
}
```

Comment: i am trying to write into a mutable Map. 
 var data = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, Either[String,Int]]
 data+=("key1"->"value")
 data+=("key2"->2)

Comment: @xrs I've added an example

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can do this with the standard collections library, however it is possible using [shapeless HMap](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#heterogenous-maps) (Heterogenous map). This is the example given in the docs, which closely matches what you have described:

```
// Key/value relation to be enforced: Strings map to Ints and vice versa
class BiMapIS[K, V]
implicit val intToString = new BiMapIS[Int, String]
implicit val stringToInt = new BiMapIS[String, Int]

val hm = HMap[BiMapIS](23 -> "foo", "bar" -> 13)
//val hm2 = HMap[BiMapIS](23 -> "foo", 23 -> 13)   // Does not compile

scala> hm.get(23)
res0: Option[String] = Some(foo)

scala> hm.get("bar")
res1: Option[Int] = Some(13)
```

Note, it doesn't give you an Any, instead you have to specify what is valid in your key/value pairs. I'm not sure if that's helpful to you or not...